# Python Pandas GroupBy Aggregate Collect_List Collect_Set

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I am trying get a similar functionality as Spark GroupBy and Collect_List or Collect_Set in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
(pd.DataFrame
         (
             {
                 'professorid' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2],
                 'studentid': ['a','b','c', 'd','e','b','b']
             }
         )
         .groupby
         (
             'professorid'
         )
         .agg
         (
             num_students = ('studentid' , 'count'),
             studentids = ('studentid' ,  lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
         )
)
```

This is giving an error:

> KeyError: "[('studentid', '')] not in index"

The result I am looking for is like below.

[image]

How can I get to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `lambda`, you can use `unique`:

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.DataFrame
         (
             {
                 'professorid' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2],
                 'studentid': ['a','b','c', 'd','e','b','b']
             }
         )
         .groupby
         (
             'professorid'
         )
         .agg
         (
             num_students = ('studentid' , 'count'),
             studentids = ('studentid' ,  'unique')
         )
)

             num_students studentids
professorid                         
1                       2     [a, b]
2                       2        [b]
3                       1        [c]
4                       1        [d]
5                       1        [e]
```

Comment: I was looking for this for ages, with terms like "unexplode" and "opposite of explode", since that's essentially what it is. Thanks.